# use \set variable inside plpgsql declare block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

My SQL script contains the following:

```
\set test 'some value'  
DO $$DECLARE  
  v_test text:= :'test';  
BEGIN  
  RAISE NOTICE 'test var is %',v_test;  
END$$;
```

I get a syntax error when trying to evaluate the value of test:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
```

Ideally I'd like to have an anonymous plpqsql block living in a file which will then get called from a shell script using a set of environment variables

Comment: This answer demonstrates an alternative solution to the duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is, [according to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION):

> Variable interpolation will not be performed within quoted SQL literals and identifiers.

The body of the `DO` statement is a (dollar-quoted) string. So no interpolation inside the string.

Since it must be a literal string, you can also not concatenate strings on the fly. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html#AEN81550)

> This must be specified as a string literal, just as in `CREATE FUNCTION`.

But you can concatenate the string and then execute it.

> ```
> \set [ name [ value [ ... ] ] ]
> ```

> Sets the psql variable name to value, or **if more than one value is
> given, to the concatenation of all of them.**

Bold emphasis mine. You just have to get the quoting right:

```
test=# \set test 'some value'
test=# \set code 'DECLARE v_test text := ' :'test' '; BEGIN RAISE NOTICE ''test var is: %'', v_test; END'
test=# DO :'code';
NOTICE: test var is: some value
DO
test=#
```

But I would rather create a (temporary) function and pass the value as parameter (where psql interpolation works). Details in this related answer on dba.SE:

- [CREATE SEQUENCE using expressions with psql variables for parameters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/139811/3684)